# Cannot expand yasnippets in .el files

Tags: yasnippet, emacs-lisp-mode

I want to use `yasnippet` in three modes. I have this in my `init.el`:

```lisp
;;; Yasnippet
(use-package yasnippet
  :commands yas-minor-mode
  :config (yas-reload-all)
  :hook ((org-mode text-mode emacs-lisp-mode) . yas-minor-mode))
```

I can create and successfully expand snippets for org-mode and text-mode. My snippets are stored here: `/home/red/.emacs.d/snippets`.

In this folder I also have a `lisp-mode` folder. A trivial example of a snippet for lisp is this:

```lisp
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: line
# key: ln
# --
;; ------------------------------------------------
;; ------------------------------------------------
```

However when I type `ln` and hit `TAB`, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them in "emacs-lisp-mode" folder.

The Emacs Lisp mode is called `emacs-lisp-mode`.